# MVC:Textbox autopopulate not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement auto-populate on a particular textbox but it is not working so far. Here's my code. What am I missing?

VIEW:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#lead-organisation").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Project/AutoCompleteOrganisation",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.Organisation, value: item.Organisation };
                            }))

                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                }
            });
        })
    </script>


      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="@Html.IdFor(x => x.Organisation)">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Organisation)
            </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Organisation, new { @class = "form-control", data_project = "organisation", editorId="lead-organisation" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Organisation)
        </div>
```

My CONTROLLER:

```
[AjaxOnly]
    public ActionResult AutoCompleteOrganisation(string term)
    {
        var taxonomy = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<TaxonomyHelper>();
        var organisationList = new ProjectOrganisationModel();
        organisationList.Organisation = taxonomy.GetOrganisations();

        var result = from org in organisationList.Organisation
                     where org.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                     select org.Name;

        return Json(result, "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have also downloaded this:jquery.autocomplete.js and added it on my BundleConfig.cs
.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")

Comment: You get any console errors?

Comment: You don't have an element with `id="lead-organisation"` (but you do have one with `id="Organisation"`) - it needs to be `$("#Organisation").autocomplete({ ...`

Comment: I am using IE and there are no errors popping for JS. Will use FireBug?

Comment: I think OP is trying to connect with `editorId` where he has mentioned same `id` and I don't think it will work right @StephenMuecke

Comment: I had editorID=lead-organisation.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao no console errors, everything returns 200 OK upon checking in FireBug

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, `TextBoxFor(x => x.Organisation, ...)` generates `<input type="text" id="Organisation" ...>` All OP has done is create invalid html using `new { editorId="lead-organisation" }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yea.. That's what I was concerned.. I wasn't sure whether there was something called `editorId` attribute.. But I knew `x=>x.Organisation` will generate `id="Organisation"` as you have mentioned the same in one of your answers for my question..

Comment: @JADE Try changing `id` to `#Organisation` instead of `#lead-organisation` for initialization on element as Stephen mentioned..

Comment: Changed it to #Organisation but still not working...

Comment: @JADE, It would work if you used `new { id="lead-organisation" }` but what is the point of changing the `id` attribute. And you should be using just `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Organisation)` rather than you 3 lines of code.

Comment: Does your control get hit? Had a break point on controller method.?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i had a breakpoint at the control but it does not hit when i type anyting on the textbox.

Comment: then your plugin initialization haven't attached that `event`.. Can you show from where you got the plugin?

Comment: Got it from here: https://code.google.com/p/jqac/downloads/detail?name=jquery.autocomplete.js&can=2&q=

Comment: You say you added `jquery.autocomplete.js` to your bundle but did you also add the css file? (Found at https://code.google.com/p/jqac/downloads/detail?name=jqac.css&can=2&q=)

Comment: @JohnC I have added the css as well but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally make it work.

Used this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#lead-organisation").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("AutoCompleteOrganisation", "Project")'
            });
        })
</script>
```

For controller:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteOrganisation(string term)
{
    var taxonomy = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<TaxonomyHelper>();
    var organisationList = new ProjectOrganisationModel();
    organisationList.Organisation = taxonomy.GetOrganisations();

    var match = organisationList.Organisation.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).
        Select(e => e.Name).Distinct().ToList();

    return Json(match, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then I did not download any autocomplete plugin, instead just use:
jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js
jquery-2.1.1.js

Thank you for answering my queries.